# scrapy the spider crawls ursl although the request_seen returns true

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy 0.20 with python 2.7

I want to avoid duplicated items.

I make this custom class

```
def request_seen(self, request):
        fp = self.__getid(request.url)
        print 'we are heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeere {0}'.format(fp)
        if (fp is not None) and (fp in self.fingerprints):
            print 'sssssssssssssssssssssssss'
            return True
        elif fp is not None:
            print 'why are you here'
            self.fingerprints.add(fp)
            if self.file:
                self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)
            return False
        else:
            return False
```

Please look at it.

when I run my spider I can see the text `why are you here` which meas that the `elif` is true. and inside that `elif`, I return true. Thus, the spider should know that this url is alreayd visited and it must not visit it again.

But in my case, the spider cralws these items although the `request_seen` returns true.

#### help please

#### Edit

I have this in my setting

```
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'TestSpider.CustomFilter.CustomFilter'
```

#### edit2

this is a small print screen

[image]

Comment: Are you using this in a custom dupefilter? can you share the whole class code? Some console log could also help

Comment: @pault. yes this is the code of the dupefilter. the whole class won't be helpful. but i will tell you the summery, i have a `__getid` which returns the url or it returns none. when it returns none, that means that I want to scrapy that url. when it returns `url`, i check into the fingerprints. if that url exists in the fingerprints, i don't want to crawl it. if not, i am adding it to the fingerprints and returns false which indicate that i want to crawl that url.

Comment: what about the log, can you share that?

Comment: @pault. actually I am not loging anything yet. but I can tell you that I can see the `'why are you here` printed. what else do you want me to show please?

Comment: @pault. have you left my friend?

Comment: I was simply suggesting pasting what you "see" in your console, the print statements you added mixed with Scrapy logs (by default DEBUG level provides good information on what's downloaded or filtered)

Comment: @pault. ok I will try to give you what I see in the cmd

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50074/discussion-between-paul-t-and-user3432257)

Comment: @pault. hi my friend, I am working with deta fetch, you have told me about, and I have a problem, would you check it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583419/scrapy-delta-fetch-is-not-working thanks in advance