# scrapy delta fetch is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy 0.20

I don't want to crawl already-scraped URLs.

I am using [deltafetch](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapylib/blob/master/scrapylib/deltafetch.py#L56) addon.

I make this to my settings:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'TestSpider.deltafetch.DeltaFetch': 100,
}
DELTAFETCH_ENABLED = True
DOTSCRAPY_ENABLED = True
```

but the spider keeps crawls the already-scraped items.

#### Note

in my log file. there is no `Ignoring already visited:`, which is the words that are being logged in the deltafetch. Thus, the condition `if self.db.has_key(key):` is never becomes true

Answer (score 0):

I would ask for clarification but I can't. So I'll just say, I ran into the same issue. I was simply crawling a site and taking the response bodies and writing them to a file:

```
def parse_funstuff(self, response):
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-1]
    open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

scrapy+deltafetch did not see that as scraping anything and therefore did not log it to the deltafetch db.

If you are doing the same or similar, either implement the file download as an item (not sure how to do that yet), or implement a work around as I did; I simply implemented an item in the parse_funstuff that I populate with an arbitrary value I scrape from the target xml files. This gets written to the output xml file, "scrapy crawl test_fun --set FEED_FORMAT=xml" which is different than the xml files I'm downloading. This way, scrapy+deltafetch sees that something was scraped from each of the .xml file URLs and ignores it on subsequent crawls. I added the following to the parse_funstuff:

```
    xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
    xxs.remove_namespaces()
    sites = xxs.select("//funstuff/morefun")
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = FunItem()
        item['stuff'] = site.select("//funstuff/FunStuff/funny/ID").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

This resolved my issue with scrapy+deltafetch. Check your logs and make sure scrapy+deltafetch thinks you've actually scraped something, just a "GET" doesn't seem to be enough, make sure you're seeing "Scraped from" in your logs.